# What is the recommended memory_target and memory_max_target for ORACLE 12 DB running on a dedicated server with 32GB RAM?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

What is the recommended `memory_target` and `memory_max_target` for ORACLE DB running on a dedicated linux server with 32GB RAM?

The server is dedicated to the Oracle 12 database.

Is there any recommendations in such case?

Comment: It's very difficult to establish those limits without knowing a bit about the Db's workload. Nevertheless, i would reserve as most memory as i can (just leaving enough for the OS), and then let AMM (Automatic Memory Manager) do the work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget `memory_target` and `memory_max_target`. AMM has always been a feature that worked on paper, but failed in practice. Oracle finally admitted it semi-officially as of the release of 12.2:

[image]

When I have no information about earlier memory usage, I just go with a 1:4 ratio for PGA:SGA target.

```
sga_target=20G
pga_aggregate_target=5G
```

Which implicitly sets:

```
sga_max_size=20G
pga_aggregate_limit=10G
```

Then later you can tune if needed, after observing the workload and memory usage.

Comment: Fully agree. Just to complete the answer - you also should properly configure Huge Pages on Linux and set `USE_LARGE_PAGES = ONLY`.

Comment: So on a 32 GB dedicated server you recommend SGA+PGA=25GB? which is about 80% of the total memory?

Comment: Hi. Would be grateful to get your opinion on my issue here https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/265187/180495

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a PGA to SGA ratio of 2:5 based on the following facts and findings.

#### PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET

The parameter `PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET` when not defined will default to the greater of `10 MB` or `20% of SGA` as mentioned in the official docs:

> ```
> Default value : 10 MB or 20% of the size of the SGA, whichever is greater
> ```

<sup>***Reference:*** [1.213 PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-DEBBD3F7-9F6D-4AC8-952C-0E0B2E62312D.htm#REFRN10165) (Oracle Docs)</sup>

#### PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT

The parameter `PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT` when not defined will default to the greater of `2 GB`, `200%  PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET` or `3MB * Proceses` as mentioned in the official docs:

> ```
> Default value : By default, PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT is set to the greater of 2 GB, 
>                 200% of PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET, and 3 MB times the PROCESSES parameter. 
>                 It will be set below 200% of PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET if it is larger 
>                 than 90% of the physical memory size minus the total SGA size, but 
>                 not below 100% of PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET.
> ```

<sup>***Reference:*** [1.212 PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-E364D0E5-19F2-4081-B55E-131DF09CFDB3.htm#REFRN10328) (Oracle Docs)</sup>

#### Worst Case

In a worst case scenario PGA could be 40% the size of SGA.

#### In Your Case

Splitting up the 32 GB I would round down to 28 GB (leave 4 GB for the OS) and then split in a ratio of 2 to 5:

```
PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT = 8G 
SGA_MAX_MEMORY = 20G
```

---

> **Why this additional answer?**
>   This answer is a slight variation of Balazs Papp's explanation (who I hold to the highest esteem) based on my current experience and the documentation provided by Oracle. It is here solely for the purpose of explaining why I come to a slightly different conclusion.

Comment: Hi. Would be grateful to get your opinion on my issue here dba.stackexchange.com/q/265187/180495

Comment: @TrojanName  I will have a look at your question.  I've favourited your question already.

Comment: Thank you John, I appreciate it!